# vba display message box when cell changes?

Tags: excel, vba

I am wanting to display a message box each time the cell value in my column is changed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells.Count < 3 And Target.Column = 13 Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("M:M")) Is Nothing Then

    MsgBox "hEY"
End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Ideally i'd like to try and avoid worksheet change event since this seems to slow down my spreadhseet for everything else, including when users type in other cells. The cursor shows a loading cursor as if vba is trying to work in the background.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: find the time to give feedbacks to previous answers you got here on your previous posts, I see that you didn't accept any of them or/and marked as "ANSWER"

Comment: ??? any feedbacks for the answers below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simplify your code, just check if the cells being changed are in Column M, and then check that the number of cells is less than 3.

If those 2 `If`s are not met, the code does nothing, just goes directly to `End Sub`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("M:M")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Cells.Count < 3 Then MsgBox "Hey"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can't display a `MessageBox` without putting code in the event. The best you can do is to test the conditions that will likely fail first, so the code test fewer times conditions inside de event and run faster.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("M:M")) Is Nothing Then GoTo Quit
    If Target.Cells.Count < 3 Then GoTo Quit

    MsgBox "Hey!"
Quit:
End Sub
```

In my experience, you should avoid this kind of code because of the reasons you stated. I always set my worksheet free and create a 'Validate' button that points out the user where errors were found (tough I don't know what you want to accomplish with your code).